# How do I stop Previous / Next buttons from displaying hidden divs?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, popup, imagebutton

(ASP.NET-MVC) platform

I have a popup dialog that also has prev/next buttons in the header to cycle through a series of different dialogs without closing the popup. Works fine, but there are hidden divs before the first hidden popup div and the previous button is displaying the unwanted hidden div when the first (wanted) hidden div is displayed and I click prev…Make sense?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's a sample of the HTML:

```
<div class="uptitle">
    <img src="/Images/btnLeftArrow.png" onclick="GetPreviousAttachmentQuestion()" style="margin: 0 0 -4px 0;" alt="">
    <label id="AttachmentSurveyDataId" hidden=""></label>
    <label id="AttachmentInputFieldId" hidden=""></label>
    <label id="AttachmentPropertySurveyId" hidden=""></label>
    <h3 style="display: inline"><span data-bind="text: FieldLabel"></span></h3>
    <img src="/Images/btnRightArrow.png" onclick="GetNextAttachmentQuestion()" style="margin: 0 0 -4px 0;" alt="">
    <br>
    <br>                   
</div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
var GetPreviousAttachmentQuestion = function () {
    var currentSurveyDataId = $('#AttachmentSurveyDataId').text();
    if (currentSurveyDataId != "") {
        var currentDiv = $('div > input[value="' + currentSurveyDataId + '"]').closest($('div'));
        var previousQuestion = $(currentDiv).prev($('div > img[onclick^="PopAddPhotosDialog"]'));

        if ($('#AttachmentSurveyDataId').text() == "Front View")
            previousQuestion.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        else if (previousQuestion.length == 0)
            return;

        var previousSurveyId = ($('input[name^="SurveyDatas"][name$=".Id"]', previousQuestion.closest($('div')))).val();
        var previousInputFieldId = $('input[name^="SurveyDatas"][name$=".InputField_Id"]', previousQuestion).val();
        var propertySurveyId = $('#AttachmentPropertySurveyId').text();
        SetupAddPhotosWidget(previousInputFieldId, previousSurveyId, propertySurveyId);
    }
};
```

(Next button is identical, except it uses ".next()")

Comment: That would depend on the JavaScript you're using, and the HTML of the page in which it's used.

Comment: @ David Thomas I included a code example...

Comment: Would you mind to add a screenshot? :)